# Javascript getElementByID().innerHTML() works on the second click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have here this code. Selected index is a textbox here from my C# program. My problem is it takes two clicked on the Show Popup button before it transfer the text of SelectedIndex to the function. I really don't know if its because of the getElementByID().innerHTML().

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Popup" 

  OnClientClick="ShowPopUp('#SelectedIndex');" onclick="Button1_Click1" />



<script type="text/javascript">

    ShowPopUp = function() {

        var x = document.getElementById('<%=SelectedIndex.ClientID %>').innerText;

        window.showModalDialog('CopyFiles/'+x, window, 'dialogWidth:800px;dialogHeight:800px;center:yes;resizable:0;status:0;scrollbars:no;menubar:0;titlebar:no;toolbar:0;');

   }
```

ANYONE? WHO CAN HELP ME? :X Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bad design - you press the button, you open the window, make full post back the index change to A. Then you press again, now you get the A, now the window open correctly, but you have one more post back. Redesign your steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is because the the selected index doesn't get set until after the button is clicked and the postback happens. Instead of setting the value of getElementById with a server side variable... instead... look at getting the value of the selected dropdown using javascript.

For Example. Some code to get the selected drop down value in javascript.

```
<select id="ddl">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
</select>

var myDDL = document.getElementById("ddl");
var val = myDDL.options[myDDL.selectedIndex].value;
```

---

Some minor tweaks to your code (not tested).

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Popup" 
  OnClientClick="ShowPopUp();" onclick="Button1_Click1" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowPopUp() 
    {
        var myDDL = document.getElementById("ddl");
        var val = myDDL.options[myDDL.selectedIndex].value;    

        //var x = document.getElementById('ddl').innerText;

        window.showModalDialog('CopyFiles/' + val, window, 'dialogWidth:800px;dialogHeight:800px;center:yes;resizable:0;status:0;scrollbars:no;menubar:0;titlebar:no;toolbar:0;');

   }
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer. It may hepl others also.